# Why do I get "Internal Server error 500" when subscribing to mailchimp in Rails, but it complete the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, mailchimp

I am trying to get a user subscription going in Rails with Mailchimp and GIbbon gem.

I have the form working right now, and I can subscribe user to mailchimp. When I hit submit, the browser console returns this error. BUT the my mailchimp list gets updated with the new user, and that user email gets a confirmation. Why does this happen?

```
POST http://localhost:3000/subscribe 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?
```

Here is my form

```
<%=form_tag( url_for( :action=>'consubscribe'), method: "post", id: "subscribe", remote:        "true") do -%>
<%=text_field_tag(:name, nil, {class: "form-control", :placeholder=>"John Smith",:required => true} ) %>
<input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone" type="phone" required />
<%=phone_field_tag(:phone,nil, {class: "form-control", :placeholder=>"647-232-1234",:required => true} ) %>
<% end %>
```

here is the corresponding action

```
def consubscribe

@list_id = "1d8d6b92f2"
gb = Gibbon::API.new

gb.lists.subscribe({
  :id => @list_id,
  :merge_vars  => {:NAME => params[:name],:PHONE => params[:phone]},

  :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]},
  :double_optin => false,
  :send_welcome => true
  })

end
```

here is my route

```
 post '/subscribe' => 'main#consubscribe'
```

Now I also want to perform some jquery action after the submit is sucessful. Right now, the form does nothing after you hit the submit, all the fields are there, nothing is cleared out, there is no indication of success or failure.

I want the form to fade out after the request is sucessful, and give them a message, or a failure message if there is an error. How do I go about and do this?